# Unity's WebGL not working with Firebase Hosting

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase-hosting, unity-webgl

I'm trying to deploy a WebGL built with Unity to Firebase Hosting, but I'm getting an error:

`Invoking error handler due to Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`.

I can run it fine on localhost, though. I'm using the production build, not the development one, so I have the following file structure:

- index.html
- Release

  - UnityLoader.js
  - webgl.datagz
  - webgl.jsgz
  - webgl.memgz
- TemplateData (image, css and js files)

Any ideas? Anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: Same issue here

Comment: can you share snippet of index.html where you are importing your static assets. And also your firebase.json where you've setup the hosting configuration