# Host Unity WebGl on Angular app on Firebase hosting

Tags: javascript, angular5, firebase-hosting, unity-webgl

I have an angular app where I read Unity WebGl in a iframe. I use the url /assets/webgl/index.html to launch the webgl.

All works in dev, but when I deploy on Firebase, I got this error :

> UnityLoader.js:1 Invoking error handler due to Uncaught SyntaxError:
>   Unexpected token <
>   blob:https://MYPROJECT.firebaseapp.com/1002467b-4c14-4974-af91-23aca8b2f4e6:1
>   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

That's probably firebase rewrite rules because it loads a blob:[my project url]. So I think it is replacing my assets url by the default 'angular' url but I can't find anything related to this.

I've already seen those links but they're old and useless for me :

- https://forum.unity.com/threads/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token.322684/
- https://answers.unity.com/questions/1397472/webgl-build-when-uploaded-gives-me-this-error-unca.html
- [Unity's WebGL not working with Firebase Hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40369921/unitys-webgl-not-working-with-firebase-hosting)
- https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-can-i-share-a-webgl-project.452972/

Anyone faced this issue before ?

I use chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the may, my problem was in the firebase.json :

There was a rewrite rule which makes assets not accessible...

```
"rewrites": [
   {
      "source": "**",
      "destination": "/index.html"
   }
]
```

I had to add a rule like this :

```
{
  "source": "**/assets/webgl/**",
  "destination": "/assets/webgl/index.html**"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to disable compression for the site to work[image]